# MINGW: How to disable 'Treat WChar_t As Built In Type' in g++ linking shared/dynamic library

Tags: g++, dynamic-linking, mingw-w64

I built the shared libraries with MinGW and NOT treated WChar_t as a built-in type

```
#ifdef _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED
    typedef wchar_t UShort; // Treat as Built In
#else
    typedef unsigned short UShort; // NOT treated as Built In
#endif
```

When linking the shared libraries with a small program,

*g++ -o helloworld main.cpp -I../include/.. -L../lib -l..* // By default treating WChar_t as a built-in type and getting the compilation error (undefined reference to `)

I have checked the g++ command-line options here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html
and also tried the below option

> With -fpreprocessed, predefinition of command line and most
> builtin macros is disabled.  Macros such as "**LINE**", which are
> contextually dependent, are handled normally.  This enables
> compilation of files previously preprocessed with "-E
> -fdirectives-only".

But not succeed, the error remains.

Comment: What's the rest of this error message?: `undefined reference to`

Comment: @ssbssa undefined reference to XMethod"(unsigned short const*)",  method declaration: const UShort* XMethod() const

Comment: note that Standard C++ requires wchar_t to be a built-in type

Answer (score 0):

By setting the flag *-D_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED=OFF* works.

> g++ -D_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED=OFF -o helloworld main.cpp
> -I../include/.. -L../lib -l..

Thank you